# Define and inject a map in EJB 3.1 or CDI

Tags: spring, ejb, cdi, ejb-3.1

After several years developing in Spring, I switched to EJB and I am not happy that I have no solution for this use-case. Let's say it is the strategy pattern implemented by a map. In Spring, it could look like this.

```xml
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBeanImpl">
    <property name="handlers">
        <map>
            <entry key="foo" value-ref="fooHandler"/>
            <entry key="bar" value-ref="barHandler"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In EJB/CDI, I have this.

```java
@Stateless
public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean {

    private Map<String, Class<? extends Handler>> handlers = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        handlers.put("foo", FooHandlerImpl.class);
        handlers.put("bar", BarHandlerImpl.class);
    }

    //jndi lookup handlerClass.getSimpleName()

}
```

Mind that jndi lookup works with implementations, not interfaces. Isn't there any better solution? And no, I do not want to have separate fields (foo, bar), inject them and create the map afterwards (It can be huge list and changed often). Ideally, in case of any configuration change, I would not touch the MyBeanImpl class at all.

Comment: Why do you have a requirement to do it via a `Map`?

Comment: @JohnAment Because I call something like this: handles.get(variableDeterminingStrategy).handle(context);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more CDI like way would look something like:

```
@Qualifier
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Handles {
    String value();
}


public class HandlerLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<Handles> implements Handles{
    private final String value;
    public HandlerLiteral(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

You would then annotate each of your `Handler` implementations with `@Handles("someName")`, e.g. the class name as you're using it here.  The use of a qualifier here is more in line with how CDI works, and we use the internal `Instance` object to resolve appropriate beans.  Then in your service code (or wherever) you would simply do:

```
@Inject @Any
private Instance<HandlerService> handlerInstance;

...
handlerInstance.select(new HandlerLiteral("whateverName")).get().handle(context);
```

If you're really constrained to using a map, this wouldn't work for you.  But this should allow for more dynamic registration and essentially looks at every handler in your context.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Inject @Any
private Instance<Handler> handlers;

private Map<String, Handler> handlerMap = new HashMap<>();


@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    for (Handler handler : handlers) {
        handlerMap.put(handler.getName(), handler);
    }
}
```

assuming your `Handler` interface has some sort of `getName()` method.

Comment: Ok, it is not as elegant as I expected, but at least it works. Moreover handlers have to be java files, not only xml configuration of only one class but it would be a different question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318848/how-to-instantiate-more-then-one-cdi-weld-bean-for-one-class