# How to instantiate more CDI beans for one class?

Tags: java, cdi, java-ee-7

**Note**: The similar question has been already asked three years ago, in time of EE 6, see [how to instantiate more then one CDI/Weld bean for one class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318848/how-to-instantiate-more-then-one-cdi-weld-bean-for-one-class/5539635) Has something changed in **EE 7**?

In Spring there is possible to instantiate any class by defining the corresponding bean in xml conf. It is also possible to instantiate **more beans for one class** with different  parameters.....

Is it possible to do it in CDI, I mean to create an instance without creating another class?

Spring Example:

```xml
<bean id="foo" class="MyBean">
    <property name="someProperty" value="42"/>
</bean>
<bean id="hoo" class="MyBean">
    <property name="someProperty" value="666"/>      
</bean>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create qualifiers FooQualifier,HooQualifier and Producer for MyBean, something like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyBeanProducer {

    @Produces
    @FooQualifier
    public MyBean fooProducer() {
        return new MyBean(42);
    }

    @Produces
    @HooQualifier
    public MyBean hooProducer() {
        return new MyBean(666);
    }
}
```

Then if you somewhere do:

```
    @Inject
    @FooQualifier
    private MyBean foo;
```

You will have MyBean instance with foo.getSomeProperty() equal to 42 and if you do:

```
@Inject
@HooQualifier
private MyBean hoo;
```

you will have MyBean instance with foo.getSomeProperty() equal to 666.

Another possibility is to have one configurable qualifier:

```
@Target( { TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Qualifier
public @interface ConfigurableQualifier {

    @Nonbinding
    int value() default 0;
}
```

and then producer method:

```
@Produces
@ConfigurableQualifier
public MyBean configurableProducer(InjectionPoint ip){
    int somePropertyValue = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(ConfigurableQualifier.class).value();
    return new MyBean(somePropertyValue);
}
```

then simply calling:

```
@Inject
@ConfigurableQualifier(value = 11)
private MyBean configurableBean;
```

will result in MyBean instance with someProperty equal to 11.

Comment: Nice, it works even for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113624/define-and-inject-a-map-in-ejb-3-1-or-cdi